# Feature vector in HSV space

Tags: image, matlab

I tend to use HSV as the feature to represent each pixel, then I can use bag-of-word model to do further processing, such as classification.

I read about this from paper[1]

> Each region is modeled using the multivariate histogram of the HSV
>   values of its pixels with 8 bins used for the H channel and 3 bins for
>   each of S and V channels, resulting in a 72-dimensional feature
>   vector.

I know it's easy to use matlab or python to get image color space for an image, but I confuse how to obtain a 72-dim feature vector as described above. Any existing code to do this (better in matlab)?

[1]: Scene Classification Using Bag-of-Regions Representations, CVPR 07

Answer (score 4):

The 72 dimensional vector which is comprised of 3 subvectors of dimensions 8, 3 and 3 means:

For Hue color space which normally gives a 360 degree value you quantize it to 8 bins. That is `360/8 = 45` per bin:
`0-45` get value `0`
`46-90` get value `1` etc.

Similarly for Saturation (normally gets value `0-1`) and Value (`0-1`) means each bin get values:
`1/3 = 0.3333`.
`0-0.333` get value 0 
`0.334-0.666` get value 1 etc.

Finally you concatenate them and you get a 72 dim vector.